# Bind ObservableList<TextField> to ListProperty<String> JFX

Tags: java, data-binding, javafx

**Given**

I have a model class `Model` that contains the following fields:

`StringProperty stringProperty; ListProperty<String> listOfStringsProperty`

I have a view class `View extends VBox` that has the following:

`TextField stringTextField; TextFieldList stringsTextFieldList;`

`TextFieldList extends VBox` is a custom class that I created that handles multiple `TextFields` with nice + and - buttons to add and remove input text fields.

`TextFieldList` class contains the field `ObservableList<Node> inputTextFields` and I can get the data from these InputTextFields by a method call `List<String> getData()`

**Question**

I was able to do the following:

```
stringTextField.textProperty().bindBidirectional(model.getStringProperty());
```

in order to bind the result of the `stringTextField` in `View` to the `stringProperty` in `Model`

And I need to do something like

```
stringsTextFieldList.listProperty().bindBidirectional(model.getListOfStringsProperty());
```

How can I do that?

If this design would not work, then how do you suggest I fix it? Is there a built-in class that does the same as `TextFieldList` but instead `extends Control`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you decide to make your own control you should create the "binding manually", that means that in the input `ObservableList` you add a [ListChangeListener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.html) then you process the [Change](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/ListChangeListener.Change.html) like in the example: check whether a new item is added, removed or updated and maintain your `TextField`s accordingly. It is possible, but my answer is mainly about proposing an existing control to re-use rather than create your own one.

**So if you don't want to re-invent the wheel:**

I don't know your exact use-case, but maybe it is reasonable to reuse a control that actually support a data model, like a [ListView](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html).

In the example I have modified the Model class to have an `ObservableList<StringProperty>` rather than a `ListProperty<String>` (note: it is also possible to simply have `String` objects in the list, I just modified it to make the binding really clear). I have added a `ListView` and used [setCellFactory](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/ListView.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) to draw `TextField`s as elements in the list which are bidirectionally bounded to the corresponding `StringProperty` in the list. I have also added several buttons to add and remove elements and a button to print the current content of the model.

**Example:**

*Model.java*

```
public class Model {

    public ObservableList<StringProperty> listOfStringsProperty;

    public Model(){
        listOfStringsProperty = FXCollections.observableArrayList();    
    }

}
```

*Main.java*

```
public class Main extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        try {
            BorderPane root = new BorderPane();
            Scene scene = new Scene(root,400,400);      

            Model m = new Model();
            m.listOfStringsProperty.addAll(new SimpleStringProperty("First"),
                    new SimpleStringProperty("Second"),
                    new SimpleStringProperty("Third"));

            ListView<StringProperty> lv = new ListView<StringProperty>();
            lv.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<StringProperty>, ListCell<StringProperty>>() {

                @Override
                public ListCell<StringProperty> call(ListView<StringProperty> param) {
                    return new ListCell<StringProperty>(){

                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(StringProperty item, boolean empty) {

                            super.updateItem(item, empty);

                            if(item == null){
                                setText(null);
                                setGraphic(null);
                                return;
                            }

                            TextField tf = new TextField();
                            tf.textProperty().bindBidirectional(item);
                            setGraphic(tf);
                        }
                    };
                }
            });


            lv.setItems(m.listOfStringsProperty);

            root.setCenter(lv);

            // Control buttons
            HBox hbox = new HBox();
            Button buttonAdd = new Button("Add");
            buttonAdd.setOnAction(e -> m.listOfStringsProperty.add(new SimpleStringProperty("")));

            Button buttonRemove = new Button("Remove last");
            buttonRemove.setOnAction(e -> m.listOfStringsProperty.remove(m.listOfStringsProperty.size()-1));

            Button buttonPrintModel = new Button("Print model");
            buttonPrintModel.setOnAction(e -> System.out.println(m.listOfStringsProperty.toString()));

            hbox.getChildren().addAll(buttonAdd, buttonRemove, buttonPrintModel);


            root.setBottom(hbox);

            primaryStage.setScene(scene);
            primaryStage.show();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

*This will produce the following window:*

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 
[Bindings.bindContent(List list1, ObservableList list2)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/beans/binding/Bindings.html#bindContent-java.util.List-javafx.collections.ObservableList-).

This is a special binding that keeps the list in sync with the observable list. Keep in mind that this is not bidirectional though.

If bidirectorionality is what you want, you should use invalidation listeners or change listeners to detect changes and synchronize the lists manually. You might need some crude locking mechanism to prevent a stack overflow.